# Installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 is imposibble but 20 i possible

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi

I have new laptop Lenovo ideapad gaming 3 15arh05 with ryzen 7 4800H and Nvidia GTX 1650ti. For work I need to use Ubuntu 18 with Ros Melodic but I am unable to install this system, I tried Ubuntu 20 and it worked perfectly. I tried with diffrent options like secure boot, uefi/legacy. When I choose TRY UBUNTU, I get errors:

pci ... AMD-VI: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
nouveau DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22
sd [sda] No Caching mode page found
sd [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Then I see purple screen and get over 100 errors
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
[OK] Started Session c(numbers from 5 to 99) of user gdm.
[OK] Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
[OK] Created slice User Slice of gdm.

Then process freezes and I need to reboot laptop.

I have fought for 6 days. Maybe I don't see everything and I do mistake somewhere or should I install Ubuntu 20 and somehow try to install Ros Melodic?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 is a very different product to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Ubuntu has had *snap* only products that are identified by the use of *year* only since 2016, but are you sure you're comparing Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as they are different products?  Please clarify and correct.  (18 & 18.04.5 are likewise different Ubuntu products)

Answer (score 3):

You're laptop is probably too new for the kernel provided with the setup of Ubuntu 18.04. The two simplest solution I see :

1. Use the ROS provided for ubuntu 20.04 http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation
2. Install ubuntu 18.04 as a virtual machine with [gnome-boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) or [virtualbox](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will install ubuntu 18 as a VM.